# Send image from local storage via JSON

Tags: java, json, spring

I am working on a java web application using Spring MVC. I need to send an image of a resource using JSON from local storage(suppose in D:\Work\ResourceData\Employee1\Employee1.jpg) to an URL. How can I perform that? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Don't send Images via JSON. Provide a link to that Image via JSON and load it from your client from the URL afterwards.